# Not enough space to update apps

Tags: internal-storage, hardware

How do I make more space on my phone to update apps or download more stuff if my phone has a 16GB SD card and I have 14.25GB left?

Comment: 1) All Caps doesn't help anyone at all. 2) I advise an [Edit] and add [tag:insufficient-memory] tag. 3) Do take a look at the questions under the tag [tag:insufficient-memory]. This question already has an answer. 4) Please  see [ask] and [how do I search](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/searching) to know how to ask and to look for already answered questions, respectively. 5) Enough said already. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your phone has two spaces where it can store apps, the internal memory and the SD card. It seems like the internal memory has filled up completely. To remedy this, go to Settings > Apps and move any apps you can to the SD card/external storage (by clicking an app, then click 'move to external storage' or similar). This will free up space on internal storage for it to download updates etc. whilst keeping the apps on your SD card.

You should do this for all the apps you can, as long as you don't need them to run in the background; for example, you should not do this with apps that provide widgets, or alarm clock apps.

A tip: don't ask questions in all-capitals; it doesn't encourage answers.

Comment: Also you can select default installation location to SD card in System > storage